# Unable to log Azure AD Account

Tags: azure, virtual-desktop

Why i cannot log to azure virtual desktop using AD account.

I had configured and added the access controls : Virtual Machine Administrator Login and Virtual Machine User Login.

**click me to see login failed**
[image]

**Config set up**
[image]

**Config set up**
[image]

[logs from VM](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Aroyj.png)

[Hostpool RDP advance setting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hodjW.png)

[WVD configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XvBIF.png)

Answer (score 0):

In order to connect to Virtual desktop using Azure AD, you need to enable Login with Azure AD while creating VM. Once VM created, need to add Role assignments in VM Access policy.

I have reproduced issue from my side and below are steps I followed,

1. Created VM without enabling Login with Azure AD.
2. Once VM created, I did not add any role assignment and tried to connect Virtual desktop using Azure AD authentication.
3. I got error like below,
   [image]
4. Created another new VM with enabling Login with Azure AD and added role assignments once VM created.
   [image]
5. Downloaded RDP file and connected to Virtual Desktop with Azure AD.
   [image]
   Reference [Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/devices/howto-vm-sign-in-azure-ad-windows)

Comment: Hello! I am still getting the error. I also added new pictures on my post to help me solve the problems. Thank you.

Comment: Hi...Refer below link. It may help you
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/452334/how-to-sign-in-on-azure-virtual-desktop-with-azure.html

Comment: Hello! If you can try to look at my logs which i get from my VM. Currently I can sign in using my local account but the AAD account is not signing in. I added additional images to help us solve the issue. Thank you.

Comment: I could see all the configurations done by you are proper. I would suggest you to raise a support request with Microsoft.